# Setup Subversive in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, connector

how to setup subversive in eclipse, I downloaded the plug-in and put it in "drop-ins" folder and it installed but seems it need SVN-Connector to run !!! 
If I want to enable SVN in eclipse there must be two plug-ins?!!! What is subversive and what is Connectors???

If I must have both, how can I download the Connector manually(without eclipse market place)..

REGARDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the eclipse site:

> Subversive distribution consists of
>   two parts - Subversive plug-in and
>   Subversive SVN Connectors. Both parts
>   are required in order to work with
>   Subversive. Subversive plug-in is
>   provided under the terms and
>   conditions of the Eclipse Public
>   License Version 1.0 ("EPL"). A copy of
>   the EPL is available at
>   http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html.
>   Subversive SVN Connectors are external
>   libraries with their own licenses,
>   which are distributed from an external
>   location at www.polarion.com.

Both parts are required for a working subversive setup.

Comment: I download the connector jar file, how can install it in eclipse

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/connectors_discovery.php

Answer (score 0):

A list of available connectors is here.

http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php

Also a link to an update site and an archive of connector releases.